# Template Metaprogramming Eigen Expressions

Tags: c++, eigen, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have some (short) vector, the length of which I know at compile time, and another, longer vector, the length of which I don't know at compile time.  I could write something like this:

```
template<int N>
Eigen::ArrayXd do_transformation(Eigen::Array<double,N,1> short_vec, Eigen::ArrayXd long_vec){
    Eigen::ArrayXd return_vector(long_vec.size());
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
      return_vector+=short_vec(i)*long_vec.pow(2-i);
    }
    return return_vector;
}
```

Is there a way I can construct that sum using expression templates *without* having to write out:

```
template<>
Eigen::ArrayXd do_transformation<1>(Eigen::Array<double,1,1> short_vec, Eigen::ArrayXd long_vec){

    return short_vec(0)*long_vec.pow(2);
}

template<>
Eigen::ArrayXd do_transformation<2>(Eigen::Array<double,2,1> short_vec, Eigen::ArrayXd long_vec){

    return short_vec(0)*long_vec.pow(2)+short_vec(1)*long_vec.pow(1);
}
```

for every value of N?

Ideally this could be done in `c++11`.  What would be *really* awesome would be for the function to return some kind of Eigen expression, so that I could do something like:

`long_vec+do_transformation(short_vec,long_vec)` and have Eigen direct the compiler to generate code that only traverses the vectors once.

Comment: C++98, C++11, C++14 or C++17 ?

Comment: Is the `2` in `pow(2-i)` fixed or always `N-1`? Do you actually do polynomial evaluation, or is this just a toy example?

Comment: @chtz the 2 is actually a 2.  Note that for N>2, pow(2-N) will be negative, which I need to be able to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c++11 you can do a good old recursion:

```
template <int I>
struct do_transformation_impl {
    template<int M>
    static auto run(const Array<double,M,1> &short_vec, const ArrayXd &long_vec)
    -> decltype(short_vec(I)*long_vec.pow(2-I) + do_transformation_impl<I-1>::run(short_vec,long_vec))
    {
        return short_vec(I)*long_vec.pow(2-I) + do_transformation_impl<I-1>::run(short_vec,long_vec);
    }
};

template <>
struct do_transformation_impl<0> {
    template<int M>
    static auto run(const Array<double,M,1> &short_vec, const ArrayXd &long_vec)
    -> decltype(short_vec(0)*long_vec.pow(2))
    {
        return short_vec(0)*long_vec.pow(2);
    }
};

template<int N>
auto do_transformation(const Array<double,N,1> &short_vec, const ArrayXd &long_vec)
-> decltype(do_transformation_impl<N-1>::run(short_vec,long_vec))
{
    return do_transformation_impl<N-1>::run(short_vec,long_vec);
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/4xPdVm

After some adjustments of max66's answer, both solution yield to the same code: https://godbolt.org/z/Ha5qMa

Comment: "After some adjustments of max66's answer, both solution yield to the same code" - intriguing.

Comment: Look at the demo, I only changed the returned types to be expression and argument types to pass them by reference.

Comment: I see, I see... I find intriguing that two C++ codes, so different, generate compiled codes almost equal.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++17, I suppose you can use an helper function (`dth()`, in the following example), `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence` and template folding.

Something as follows (caution: code not tested):

```
template <int N, std::size_t ... Is>
Eigen::ArrayXd dth (Eigen::Array<double,N,1> short_vec,
                    Eigen::ArrayXd long_vec,
                    std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 { return ((short_vec(Is) * long_vec.pow(2-Is)) + ...); }

template <int N>
Eigen::ArrayXd do_transformation (Eigen::Array<double,N,1> short_vec,
                                  Eigen::ArrayXd long_vec)
 { return dth(short_vec, long_vec, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

If you can't use C++17, but you can use C++14, the helper function become a little more complicated (if you want, I can write an example) because you can't use template folding.

```
template <int N, std::size_t ... Is>
Eigen::ArrayXd dth (Eigen::Array<double,N,1> short_vec,
                    Eigen::ArrayXd long_vec,
                    std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   Eigen::ArrayXd rv(long_vec.size());

   (void)unused { 0, (rv += short_vec(Is) * long_vec.pow(2-Is), 0)... };

   return rv;
 }
```

For a C++11 solution, you need create a replacement for `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence`.